# Problem with @OneToMany annotation with Spring Roo

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I'm trying to use Spring Roo to generate entities with a `@OneToMany` unidirectional relationship.  Here's what I've tried:

```
entity --class ~.family.Child
field string --fieldName name
controller scaffold ~.web.ChildController
entity --class ~.family.Father
field string --fieldName name
field set --fieldName children --element ~.family.Child --cardinality ONE_TO_MANY 
controller scaffold ~.web.FatherController
perform package
```

This produces the expected entities and database tables (including a link table.)  The `Father` entity is generated with the following annotation, which conforms to the JPA spec:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<family.Child> message = new java.util.HashSet<family.Child>();
```

But when I go to the Roo-generated admin page, and click `Create Father`, I find the following message:

**Create Father**

```
Name:      (field to enter name)
Children:  This relationship is managed from the Father side.
```

This looks like a bug in Roo.  Has anyone found a work-around?  Or do I have an error in here?

Comment: Just for curiosity: Does Spring roo work as expected ??? Does it fullfil your needs ???

Comment: So far, I'm very pleased with Roo, but I've only used it for several weeks, and I'm fairly inexperienced, so I didn't have much expectation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here's a workaround:  In the `fathers/create.jspx` file, Roo generates the following line:

```
<field:simple field="children" id="c:family.Father.children" messageCode="entity.reference.not.managed" 
 messageCodeAttribute="Child" z="dMKrUOiCeYNub4vNayuiWJ99s1k="/>
```

This should be replaced by:

```
<field:select field="children" id="c:family.Father.children" itemValue="id" 
 items="${children}" multiple="true" path="/children"/>
```

And it should work.

Comment: thanks..I myself was trying it..but it was not working..I looked into spring roo jira but didn't find any bug for it..

Comment: This only works for displaying the children. If you update or create the object the references aren't saved.

What to do about this?

Comment: @Hedge I'm sorry to hear that this hasn't been fixed by now, 15 months later. I have no idea what to do, and I stopped using Roo (due to a job change) shortly after posting this.

Comment: Yeah its impossible to get Roo-specific-help. All I hear is "drop the scaffolded controllers and views and do your own stuff but they are close to what I actually want so there's no point in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a bug, probably!

I had the same command. It worked with an older version of Roo, but I tried an old backup script. It is no more working.