# Spring Roo Master/Detail & @OneToMany

Tags: spring, master-detail, hibernate-onetomany

In reference to [Problem with @OneToMany annotation with Spring Roo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196666/problem-with-onetomany-annotation-with-spring-roo/3198754#3198754), the *<field:select...* solution works well for create & update.jspx.  Any idea how to get this to work for show.jspx?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial & error I found a working combination.

From my update.jspx:

```
<field:select field="venueConfig" id="c_net_sf_bookright_entity_Venue_venueConfig" itemValue="id" items="${venueconfigs}" multiple="true" path="/venueconfigs" z="2LbToeFzkMFCLmDKmonFK/d1IgU="/>
```

...the following is required in show.jspx:

```
<field:select field="venue.venueConfig" id="s_net_sf_bookright_entity_Venue_venueConfig" itemValue="id" items="${venue.venueConfig}" multiple="true" path="/venueconfigs" z="2LbToeFzkMFCLmDKmonFK/d1IgU="/>
```